# example socket.broadcast in sails

Tags: sails.js, broadcast

I'm just starting Sailsjs, I have a problem about socket.broadcast, how to create a room and some broadcast , and then the client can receive them? I hope someone give me some example.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried it? It's explained in the docs.

Comment: My English is not good , so it is difficult to learn , hope you can help me